# Selective enabling of Template class function

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class, inside which i have a normal function. But i want to enable this normal function only for certain instantiations of a template class. I looked at boost::enable_if and it doesn't suit my need exactly / may be i am not able to use it for my need.

```
typedef boost::mpl::vector< bool, int, double >  CheckTypes;

template<class X>
class P
{
    void init( int x, 
       typename boost::enable_if< boost::mpl::contains<CheckTypes, X> >::type* dummy = 0);
};
```

Can Someone help mw on how to solve this issue? An important thing is that the solution should not expect anything from the calling code. And the class is explicitly instantiated.

Thanks,
Gokul.

Comment: When you say "enable," do you mean "this function doesn't even exist unless you instantiate with types X, Y, or Z?"

Comment: I want the function to exist only for bool, int and double in my example. Is it possible?

Comment: enable_if should actually work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enable_if` is usually used to discriminate among different definitions of a function. In a certain sense, it is a more powerful way of overloading.

It seems you are trying to *enable* a function only if a condition holds, and *give a compilation error* otherwise, since you have a single definition of `init`. If that's correct, you may want to look into `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT` (or `static_assert` in c++0x) instead.

Comment: I have clarified it in the comment for the above answer. Can you help ? Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to do? My guess is that your `init` code works only when `X` is one of `CheckTypes`, but you want to be able to instantiate `P` also with other types. If this is the case, you may want to define a second `init` which is `disabled_if`d on types other than `CheckTypes`, and does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use a static assertion.  Member functions of template classes are instantiated lazily, meaning that if they're never called, the code for them won't be generated.  This means that you could write the function as usual, expecting that it will only ever be called for the instantiations of bool, int, or double, and then to insert a static assertion into this function that checks that this is indeed the case.

If, on the other hand, you can't do this because you're explicitly instantiating the template, another option might be to provide a template specialization for those three types that does include the extra member function.  This would allow you to explicitly include or exclude the function, though it might require some extra coding.

Alternatively, you might consider making this extra function not a member function of the class, but instead a free function.  For example, instead of having an `init` function that just exists for those three cases, consider defining three functions that look like this:

```
void Init(P<int>& toInit);
void Init(P<double>& toInit);
void Init(P<bool>& toInit);
```

That way, the code that might not compile for arbitrary types isn't in the general class itself, but is instead fanned out into these functions.  You could then implement these three functions in terms of some helper function that is itself a template.

Comment: Hmmm... Actually i have this class instantiated explicitly, but i am not calling the function at all. Still it reports a compile time error. This is MSVC 2010. What might be the reason???

Comment: Explicitly instantiating a template (that is, writing out something to the effect of `template class P<string>;`) will eagerly instantiate all of the member functions.  Implicitly instantiating the template (e.g. declaring a variable of type P<string>) shouldn't do this.  Is there a reason for the explicit instantiation?

Comment: Yeah!!! that was done to save compile time. Since this module gets included everywhere...

Comment: Actually the class had lot of functions. We have put the functions inside cpp file instead of the header file and instantiated the class and all the functions. I removed the instantiation of the class and only included the instantiation of the functions and it worked. Thanks...